# How do I get content of custom post type through post ID in wordpress

Tags: php

My custom post type name is movie_reviews. Inside movie reviews there are multiple post but i need only that post whose id is 244. My code for it is

```
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=movie_reviews&ID=244');
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

    the_content();
endwhile ?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at the Post & Page Parameters Section in the [`WP_Query` Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

For getting a Post by Post ID, you need to use this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=movie_reviews&p=244');
```

If you only need the content of one specific post, you can also do this:

```
$mypost = get_post(244);
echo apply_filters('the_content',$mypost->post_content);
```

In this case, you don't need to worry about the loop or the global vars getting overwritten, removing your main loop.

Comment: @benimub then please acccept this answer by clicking on thhe checkmark next to this answer. Thanks

Comment: What if you don't know the ID, but rather want to search if a specific content is in the database?

Comment: Trying to use the second example but having no success with it

Comment: Can you Post some Code?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use in loop and use for each post

```
$mypost = get_post($post->ID);
echo apply_filters('the_content',$mypost->post_content);
```